# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: certificate expired - Local or Remote?

Tags: java, ssl-certificate

I am receiving the following exception while trying to make an SSL connection to a web service.  Does this error mean my local keystore/certificate is expired, or is it that I cannot trust the remote server because it has the expired certificate?

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: certificate expired
    at com.ibm.jsse.bs.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.jsse.bs.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www.protocol.https.b.o(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www.protocol.https.q.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www.protocol.http.cg.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.net.ssl.www.protocol.https.t.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote certificate expired, webservice's appserver needs to update its cert.

Answer (score 0):

See here http://www.cs.sunysb.edu/documentation/jsse/jssefaq.html#17

E.g. set the SystemProperty javax.net.debug to ssl:

```
java -Djavax.net.debug=ssl ...
```